# How does device_open in file_operations work?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I saw [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm) example online that shows how to create a character device in linux, and I'm trying to understand how calling open by the user affects the device_open function.

The file_operations struct is define as follows:

```
static struct file_operations Fops = {
 .read = device_read,
 .write = device_write,
 .open = device_open,
 .release = device_release,};
```

And the device_open function receives the following arguments:

`static int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)`

After creating a device file with mknod, the user can open the device file name:

```
fd = open(DEVICE_FILENAME, 0);
```

What I don't understand is how this call to open makes device_open receive the inode and file it needs.

Thank you!

Comment: It's been done by means of `Path Lookup` technique, a details could be found at `Documentation/filesystems/path-lookup.txt`.

Comment: From reading the documentation, I understand that there's a search in the inode tree according to the file path. However, I didn't understand how the search for the file struct is done. Is there also a tree for the file structs? Are the inode and file struct related somehow, for example with some kind of pointer?

Comment: You need to read the code to really understand how that's work. Search for vfs_open and see how that works.

Comment: Explanation of how multiple levels of VFS worked together (what is implied by you question post) is **too broad** for Stack Overflow format. There is description of VFS in the kernel documentation: `Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt`, you may start from it. `Is there also a tree for the file structs?` - File structure is **created** when user calls `open()`. `Are the inode and file struct related somehow, for example with some kind of pointer?` - Yes, the pointer to the file operations is stored in inode object.

Comment: The driver code will have registered a range of device numbers and mapped them to a set of file operations. It could have done both in one go by calling `register_chrdev` or `__register_chrdev`, or it could have done them separately by calling `register_chrdev_region` or `alloc_chrdev_region` followed by `cdev_add` sometime later. (There may be a one `cdev_add` call for a range of device numbers, or several `cdev_add` calls for individual device numbers, or something in-between.) The driver may also have called `device_create` to create char special files in SysFS with matching device numbers.

Comment: `chrdev_open` in "fs/char_dev.c" will be called when a character special file is opened. That will look up which set of file operations has been registered to the device number by `cdev_add`, replace the file operations for the `struct file` object being opened, and call the replacement `open` file operation (if any).